# Smallest interval between successive SendInput calls

Tags: c, windows, wait, timing, sendinput

I'm typing characters into a form of a web page using [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx).

For example, to type an `a` character, I send two commands:

1. Press <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Release <kbd>A</kbd>

To type an `A` character, I need to send four commands:

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Release <kbd>A</kbd>
4. Release <kbd>Shift</kbd>

And so on. To make this work, **I have to wait a bit between successive commands**. I found that the length of the waiting interval is important: if I use **100 ms**, the above command sequences aren't always successful, but **200-250 ms** seems to be enough to make them stable. It helps to repeat a sequence if it fails. Currently my code runs successfully on lots of user PCs, but it's a bit slow due to the waiting.

To speed the code up, I would like to understand what's happening. Is there an inherent, documented limit in Windows, what makes the wait between successive `SendInput` calls inevitable? Is it possible to estimate how long I must wait at least?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No such limitation exists in Windows, a fast touch typist can easily hit 10 keys a second.  Keystrokes are always buffered.  Whatever happens in your browser with perhaps javascript executing on the onkeydown event is a black box.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you. So the trial-and-error technique remains.

Comment: @bparker I believe what Hans said, so I simply started to use 250 ms. The typing is a bit slow, but works reliably.